# jQuery MVC architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

what is the best way to create MVC architecture in jQuery?

Should I use **jQuery.extend()**?

```
jQuery.extend({
  View: function(){}
});
```

...or **jQuery Plugin**?

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.model = function() { return this; }; 

})(jQuery);
```

...or just **objects in JavaScript**?

```
var model = {}
var view = {}
var controller = {}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

Just use objects in javascript. The view can contain all the knowledge of things like jquery and other UI concerns, while the controller/model can deal with other logic and communication with the server (assuming ajax). I wrote a blog post about this:

[*MVC Pattern with Javascript*](http://codecube.net/2009/06/mvc-pattern-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great approach using jQuery.extend: http://welcome.totheinter.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-jquery/